# Is there any way to list all tables used in a stored procedure in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

Postgres query to list all tables being used in a stored procedure.

Some of the stored procedures are more than 1000 lines, so if a query can do it that will be helpful.

Comment: You can query pg_class for all table names and then pg_proc for matches on the table names. Or get some decent tooling

Comment: You have to write a query with filtering options to get the tables in a stored procedure. https://database.guide/3-ways-to-list-all-stored-procedures-that-reference-a-table-in-postgresql/

Comment: https://github.com/okbob/plpgsql_check has an option to dump dependencies for pl/pgsql functions.